# SQL Select distinct from multiple fields returning only one row

Tags: sql-server, unique, distinct-values

I have a table with the following columns in SQL Server:

```
MEMBERID, MEMBEREMAIL, FATHEREMAIL, MOTHEREMAIL, MEMBERNAME
```

`MEMBERID` is PK. The three email columns are not unique, so the same email may appear several times in the same row AND in several rows.

I am trying to extract a unique list of emails, and for each email also get a `memberid` and `membername` (it does not matter from which record).

For example if I have three rows:

```
1   x@x.com   y@y.com   y@y.com   Mark
2   z@z.com   y@y.com   x@x.com   John
3   x@x.com   y@y.com   z@z.com   Susan
```

I want to get the three emails (`x@x.com, y@y.com, z@z.com`) and for each of those a `MEMBERID` in which they appear. It does NOT which `MEMBERID` (for example for `x@X.com` I don't care if I get the values 1 and Mark or 2 and John or 3 and Susan, as long as `x@x.com` appears only once in the results.

If I use DISTINCT when trying to return the email and memberid and membername, of course I get all of the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery to normalize all emails.  Then you can use `row_number` to filter out one `memberid, membername` per email:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by email order by memberid) as rn
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  MEMBERID
                ,       MEMBERNAME
                ,       MEMBEREMAIL as email
                from    YourTable
                union all
                select  MEMBERID
                ,       MEMBERNAME
                ,       FATHEREMAIL
                from    YourTable
                union all
                select  MEMBERID
                ,       MEMBERNAME
                ,       MOTHEREMAIL
                from    YourTable
                ) as emails
        ) num_emails
where   rn = 1
```

You could also normalize the emails using the `UNPIVOT` clause, like this:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by email order by memberid) as rn
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  MEMBERID
                ,       MEMBERNAME
                ,       email
                from    YourTable
                unpivot (
                                email
                        for     emailOwner
                        in      (
                                MEMBEREMAIL,
                                FATHEREMAIL,
                                MOTHEREMAIL
                                )
                        ) as u
                ) as emails
        ) num_emails
where   rn = 1
```

Try both versions at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/):

- [`UNION ALL` version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78428/4)
- [`UNPIVOT` version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78428/3)

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the right group of distinct emails:
then you can create a cursor out of the query members and then get the comma seperated list of mails per memberid with [this concept](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/) I would create an output table for this will be easyer if you need it for future use and would make a store procedure for this to create the custom table

```
select mem.*, mails.MEMBEREMAIL
from (
    select MEMBERID,max(MEMBERNAME) as MEMBERNAME
    from table
    group by MEMBERID
)  as mem 
inner join 
(
    select distinct MEMBERID, MEMBEREMAIL
    from (
        select MEMBERID, MEMBEREMAIL
        from table
        union
        select MEMBERID, FATHEREMAIL
        from table
        union
        select MEMBERID, MOTHEREMAIL
        from table
    ) as mail
) as mails on mem.MEMBERID = mails.MEMBERID
```

Comment: This code does not generate distinct emails - running it on the sample data generates 8 rows with multiple repeats.   

John 1 x@x.com
John 1 y@y.com
Mark 2 x@x.com
Mark 2 y@y.com
Mark 2 z@z.com
Susan 3 x@x.com
Susan 3 y@y.com
Susan 3 z@z.cm